# MySQL: How can fetch SUM() of all fields in one Query?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, sum

I just want somthing like this:

```
select SUM(*) from `mytable` group by `year`
```

any suggestion?

(I am using Zend Framework; if you have a suggestion using ZF rather than pure query would be great!)

**Update:** ***I have a mass of columns in table and i do not want to write their name down one by one.***

---

No Idea??

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT      SUM(column1) + SUM(column2) + SUM(columnN) 
FROM        mytable 
GROUP BY    year
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the Zend Framework's Zend_Db_Select, your query might look like

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );

$select = $db->select()
    ->from('mytable', array('sum1' => 'SUM(`col1`)', 'sum2' => 'SUM(col2)')
    ->group('year');

$stmt = $select->query();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Refer to the [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) documentation in the ZF manual for more.

EDIT: My bad, I think I misunderstood your question.  The query above will return each colum summed, but not the sum of all of the columns.  Rewriting Maxem's query so that you can use it with a Zend Framework DB adapter, it might look like

```
$sql = '<insert Maxem's query here>';
$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
```

You might choose to use [fetchCol()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchcol) to retrieve the single result.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't want to explicitly enumerate the columnn and that you want to sum all the columns (probably excluding the `year` column) over all the rows, with grouping by year.

Note that the method `Zend_Db_Table::info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS)` will return an array containing the columns names for the underlying table. You could build your query using that array, something like the following:

```
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
$table = new Zend_Db_Table('mytable');
$fields = $table->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS);
unset($fields['year']);
$select = $table->select();
$cols = array();
foreach ($fields as $field){
   $cols[] = sprintf('SUM(%s)', $field);
}
$select->cols(implode(' + ', $cols));
$select->group('year');
```

I have not tested the specific syntax, but the core of the idea is the call to `info()` to get the fields dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Done in ZF rather than pure query and you don't have to write the name of the columns one by one.
(I assume you are extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract)

If you're asking how to write

```
select SUM(*) from `mytable` group by `year`
```

This is how it is done:

```
public function sumOfAllFields(){
 return $this->fetchAll( $this->select()->from('mytable','SUM(*)')->group('year') )->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or not using Zend...

```
function mysql_cols($table){
    $sql="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `".$table."`";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $cols=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))$cols[]=$row['Field'];
    return $cols;
}

$cols=mysql_cols("mytable");
$select_sql=array();
foreach($cols as $col){
   $select_sql[]="SUM(`".$col."`)";
} 
$select_sql=implode('+',$select_sql);

$sql="select (".$select_sql.") from `mytable` group by `year`";
```